# JavaScript - Alert is null why?

Tags: javascript, html

Why the output is null and not the length(here's the code:)

```
<i>
 <input type="text" name="webAdress" />
<input type="button" value="CheckLegnth" onclick="myFunction()" />
     <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction() {
                var webAdress = document.getElementById('webAdress');
                alert(webAdress);
            }

  </script>  
</i>
```

Comment: you didn't provide id to your input field. document.getElementById means get the particular item by its id. So you need to provide the id for your element.

Comment: There are two errors: 1) You're using `getElementByID` to try and fetch an element without an `id` 2) You're alerting the DOM element and not its value.

Comment: yeah @powerbuoy noticed it. Anhsirk has the right code and answer below

Answer (score 1):

You defined the `name` attribute on your input field and not the `id`.

So either change the attribute in the input field to this:

```
<input type="text" id="webAdress" />
```

Or adjust your JavaScript to this ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName)):

```
function myFunction() {
  var webAdress = document.getElementsByName('webAdress')[0];
  alert(webAdress);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` is use `id`, but `webAdress` is name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<i>
 <input type="text" id="webAdress" name="webAdress" />
<input type="button" value="CheckLegnth" onclick="myFunction()" />
     <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction() {
                var webAdress = document.getElementById('webAdress').value;
                alert(webAdress);
            }

  </script>  
</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" id="webAdress" name="webAdress"/>
    <input type="button" value="CheckLegnth" onclick="myFunction()" />
         <script type="text/javascript">
                function myFunction() {
                    var webAdress = document.getElementById('webAdress').value;
                    alert(webAdress);
                }

      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function myFunction() {
      var webAdress = document.getElementsByName('webAdress')[0];
      alert(webAdress);
    }
```

According to your script it should be as above.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the suggestions and ran them in chrome none of them worked except the following,

```
function myFunction() {
  var webAdress1 = webAdress.value;
  alert(webAdress1);
}
```